# How to calculate the equilibrium constant for nitrogen, hydrogen, and ammonia?

Tags: equilibrium, stoichiometry

> $\pu{2 mol}$ of $\ce{N2}$ is mixed with $\pu{6 mol}$ of $\ce{H2}$ in a closed vessel of $\pu{1 L}$ capacity. If $50\%$ of $\ce{N2}$ is converted into $\ce{NH3}$ at equilibrium, what is the value of $K_c$ (equilibrium constant) for the reaction
>   $$\ce{N2 + 3 H2 <=> 2 NH3}?$$

This is what I tried to solve it:

[image: attempt at solution]

The answer to this question is $\frac{4}{27}$ as given in the solution key.
It is only possible if the concentration of $\ce{NH3}$ is not raised to its stochiometric coefficient.
Am I doing it wrong or is the answer key wrong?

Comment: $[\ce{I2}]\mathrm{e}=(2-1)=\pu{1M}$,$[\ce{H2}]\mathrm{e}=(6-3)=\pu{3M}$,$[\ce{NH3}]\mathrm{e}=(2\times{1})=\pu{2M}$
$$k_\mathrm{C}=\frac{(2)^2}{(1)(3)^3 }=\frac{4}{27}$$

Comment: A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Can you Please suggest a title for this question

Comment: I have already changed the title of the question; I am more concerned with the image, currently I am somewhat guessing what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Should I add that "if only 50% of N2 is used"

Comment: **No.** If that really were important, I would have edited this in, while I was trying to improve the question. The title is okay as it is. This is really not the problem of the question. I really cannot understand everything in the image (I can't even read all of it), otherwise I would have already converted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few notes about your solution:

> "Both are limiting reactant"

You can neglect this idea in this problem, as the reaction is not a completion reaction, it is an equilibrium reaction.

> Your solution indicates that the amount of $\ce{NH3}~ \text{at equilibrium}=n_\mathrm{e}(\ce{NH3})=\pu{4mol}$

It is not correct, it is equal $\pu{2mol}$, it can be calculated as the following:

\begin{align}
n_\mathrm{e}(\ce{NH3}) 
&=n_\text{ formed}(\ce{NH3})\\
&=2\times{n_\text{ reacted}(\ce{N2})}\\
&= 2\times \left(2\times\frac{50}{100}\right)\\
&= 2\times{(1)}\\ 
&= \pu{2mol}
\end{align}

Use the molar ratio to calculate the amount of $\ce{H2}$ reacted:
\begin{align}
n_\text{ reacted} (\ce{H2})
&= 3\times{n_\text{ reacted}(\ce{I2})}\\
&= 3\times{(1)}\\
&= \pu{3mol}
\end{align}

Calculate The amount of $\ce{H2}$ at equilibrium:
\begin{align}
n_\mathrm{e}(\ce{H2})
&=n_\mathrm{I}(\ce{H2}) 
  -n_\text{reacted}(\ce{H2})\\ 
&= 6-3\\
&=\pu{3mol} 
\end{align}

Use the following table to determine the amount of each species at equilibrium 
in order to  calculate $K_c$ :

\begin{array}{c | c c c c c}
         &\ce{N2}       & + &\ce{3H2}      &\ce{<=>}& \ce{2NH3}   \\\hline
\text{I} &(\pu{2 mol})  &   &(\pu{6 mol})  &        &(\pu{0 mol}) \\
\text{C} &(\pu{-1 mol}) &   &(\pu{-3 mol}) &        &(\pu{2 mol}) \\
\text{E} &(\pu{1 mol})  &   &(\pu{3 mol})  &        &(\pu{2 mol})  
\end{array}

Use the expression $[i]_\mathrm{e}= \frac{n_\mathrm{e}(i)}{V}$
to calculate the concentration of each species at equilibrium:
\begin{align}
  [\ce{N2}]_\mathrm{e}  &= \frac{\pu{1 mol}}{\pu{1 L}}=\pu{1 M}\\
  [\ce{H2}]_\mathrm{e}  &= \frac{\pu{3 mol}}{\pu{1 L}}=\pu{3 M}\\
  [\ce{NH3}]_\mathrm{e} &= \frac{\pu{2 mol}}{\pu{1 L}}=\pu{2 M}\\
\end{align}

Substitute the concentration of each species at equilibrium in the following formula to calculate $K_c$:
\begin{align}
K_c &=\frac{[\ce{NH3}]^2_\mathrm{e}}{[\ce{N2}]_\mathrm{e}[\ce{H2}]^3_\mathrm{e}}\\
&=\frac{(\pu{2 M})^2}{(\pu{ 1M})(\pu{3 M})^3}\\
&=\left(\frac{4}{27}\right)\cdot \pu{L^2//mol^2}
\end{align}

Comment: The answer would be better, if it were defining the quantities and then using actual equations instead of 'word equations', like amount of $\ce{NH3}$ at equilibrium would be $n_\mathrm{e}(\ce{NH3})$. That would also get rid of MathJax not breaking properly/ flowing into the margins. ($\ce{I2}$ is probably a typo?)